# Android ormlite query sort by another table

Tags: java, android, sql-order-by, ormlite

I want to query my data from A and order-by a field from B， The field in B could be `null`. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please edit your post to show us some code and more information.

Comment: Well, I know how to sort data in a table, but I want to sort A with one field in B, A and B are asociation table.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 4.22, [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) now supports simple JOIN query syntax.  Here is the documentation for it:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/join-queries

So your query might be something like:

```
QueryBuilder<B, Integer> bQb = bDao.queryBuilder();
bQb.orderBy("someBField", true);
QueryBuilder<A, Integer> aQb = aDao.queryBuilder();
List<A> results = aQb.join(bQb).query();
```

You can also certainly use the `dao.queryRaw()` methods to construct you own query.  Here a good example how you would formulate the query:

> [SQL order by a column from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805600/sql-order-by-a-column-from-another-table)