# Using a column from a SELECT statement inside an IN statement into the main query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE (id IN (
   SELECT user_id
   FROM messages
   WHERE recipient_id='$my_user_id' ORDER BY time DESC)
  OR id IN (
   SELECT recipient_id
   FROM messages
   WHERE user_id='$my_user_id' ORDER BY time DESC))
```

The list of people I've received messages from/sent messages to appears, but they are not sorted properly. I would like new message recipients to be at the top, and old message recipients to be at the bottom. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM users u
JOIN messages m on m.recipient_id = u.id 
                or m.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = '$my_user_id' 
ORDER BY m.time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the wrong thing. For `IN`, the order doesn't matter. What you want to order is the endresult. So what you want to do is [`JOIN` your `users` table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805600) with your `messages` table, and then append `ORDER BY` to the end of the main query (and remove it from the two sub-queries, as it's not needed there).

Comment: Hi, Thank you. If it's not a problem, can you show a code sample? It would really help. Thanks!